# Printf number of character in C

Tags: c

I run this code :

```
int main () {
    long numberofchar; 
    numberofchar = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
       ++numberofchar;
    printf("Number of characters : %ld\n",numberofchar);

}
```

Result : I can type some characters on the console , but It doesn't count the character at all and neither does it print the number of characters on the screen.

Comment: So your question is basically, how to input EOF?

Comment: My question is how to display the number of characters that I type on the console.

Comment: Input EOF to your program. Then the loop will end, and the printing will occur...

Comment: ...and in case you are hitting the `Enter` key, replace `EOF` with `'\n'`